# Integrate for loop in twitter scrapper in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, web-scraping, tweepy

Hy all, I need a little wisdom.

I maage to make a scrapper using the Twitter API and Tweepy. It scrapes tweets from individual profiles. I have a list of around 100 profiles that I want to scrape tweets from, but I cant figure out how to instruct the scraper to extract data from multiple profiles and how to save the output properly in csv. I have the following code:

```
import tweepy
import time
import pandas as pd
import csv

# API keyws that yous saved earlier
api_key = ''
api_secrets = ''
access_token = ''
access_secret = ''
 
# Authenticate to Twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key,api_secrets)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_secret)
 
#Instantiate the tweepy API
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

username = "markrutte"
no_of_tweets = 3200

   try:
    #The number of tweets we want to retrieved from the user
        tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=username, count=no_of_tweets)
    
    #Pulling Some attributes from the tweet
        attributes_container = [[tweet.created_at, tweet.favorite_count,tweet.source,  tweet.text] for tweet in tweets]

    #Creation of column list to rename the columns in the dataframe
        columns = ["Date Created", "Number of Likes", "Source of Tweet", "Tweet"]

 tweets_df = pd.DataFrame(attributes_container, columns=columns)
    except BaseException as e:
        print('Status Failed On,',str(e))
        time.sleep(3)
```

In my head, I believe I should specify a list with usernames as the values. And then, for username in list: scrape tweets. However, I dont really know how to do this and am still learning. Can anyone give me some advice or know a tutorial on how I should do this?

Appreciate it.

In my head, I believe I should specify a list with usernames as the values. And then, for username in list: scrape tweets. However, I dont really know how to do this and am still learning. Can anyone give me some advice or know a tutorial on how I should do this?

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your scraping code into a function, you can then concat its results into an overall dataframe in a loop:

```py
def get_tweets(username, no_of_tweets):
    #Creation of column list to rename the columns in the dataframe
    columns = ["Date Created", "Number of Likes", "Source of Tweet", "Tweet"]
    try:
        #The number of tweets we want to retrieved from the user
        tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=username, count=no_of_tweets)
        #Pulling Some attributes from the tweet
        attributes_container = [[tweet.created_at, tweet.favorite_count,tweet.source,  tweet.text] for tweet in tweets]
        # return a dataframe
        return pd.DataFrame(attributes_container, columns=columns)
    except BaseException as e:
        print('Status Failed On,',str(e))
        # return an empty dataframe
        return pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
        
usernames = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
no_of_tweets = 3200
tweets_df = pd.concat([get_tweets(username, no_of_tweets) for username in usernames])
```